# solvability of $f(x)=1+x+x^2\equiv 0\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$f(x)=1+x+x^2$ is a factor of   $g(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$.

For $p>5, g(x)\equiv0\pmod p$ has a solution if $p\equiv 1\pmod 5.$

So $f(x)\equiv0\pmod p$ when we have $p\equiv 1\pmod 5.$

$1+x+x^2$ is also a factor of   $h(x)=1+x+x^2+...+x^{10}+x^{11}$.

For $p>11, h(x)\equiv0\pmod p$ has a solution if $p\equiv 1\pmod {11}.$

So $f(x)\equiv0 \pmod p$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod 5$ and $p\equiv 1\pmod {11}.$

Is this sound logic? What am I missing here?

Comment: how do you know that $g(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ has a solution if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$? $p=7$ has a solution.

Comment: Note that when $p>3$, roots of $f(x)$ are non-trivial roots of $x^3-1=(x-1)f(x)$.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how you get that there is a solution to $g(x)\equiv 0$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod 5$.

Comment: Indeed, there is no solution for $p = 11 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.

Answer (score 1):

The logic fails starting from the claim that $g(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ has a solution if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ - $p=7$ has a solution ($x=2$).

The general way to solve this type of problems is to use quadratic residues.

This is not solvable for $p=2$, and it is solvable for $p=3$. Let us look at $p \ge 5$.

$$x^2+x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \iff 4x^2+4x+4 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \iff (2x+1)^2 \equiv -3 \pmod{p} \iff \left( \frac{-3}{p} \right) = 1$$

Also, we have $$\left( \frac{-3}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{3}{p}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = \frac{(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}{\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)} \cdot (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{p}{3}\right)} = \left(\frac{p}{3}\right)$$

Therefore, we need $\left( \frac{p}{3} \right)=1$, so $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

The solution set is $p=3$ and $p=3k+1$.